# Can you use ifinstance in a list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, syntax-error, list-comprehension

I am trying to run this line of code,

```
 revert = [chr(intchange[i]).lower() if isinstance(intchange[i], int) for i in range(len(data))]
```

but it is giving me this error

```
    revert = [chr(intchange[i]).lower() if isinstance(intchange[i], int) for i in range(len(data))]
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

anyone know if this is a glitch or something, I really don't understand why this wouldn't work?! Thank you so much!
Also, I am really trying to keep this in one line...

Comment: Thank you! Sorry lol...

Comment: Yes; the problem is that you are trying to write a conditional expression without the `else` part. `a if b` is not a valid expression; `a if b else c` is.

Comment: I'm not sure here, but if you want to filter on `isinstance(intchange[i], int)`, then you can put it after the `for` expression.It will basically become `[x for x in y if x]`.

Comment: If `intchange[i]` is *not* an integer, what should happen? Should that value be skipped entirely? Or do you want to put something else into `revert` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add `else`, try this.

```
revert = [chr(intchange[i]).lower() if isinstance(intchange[i], int) else intchange[i].lower() for i in range(len(data))]
```